# Android - Scroll to off screen view inside recycler

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am trying to scroll to an off screen element from a recycler view. I have a list of 15 languages. When app starts the user can select one language from the recycler. Then if the app starts again the recycler scrolls to that item.

But imagine the user selects the last language from the list which is not showed in the recycler when the app starts. How to scroll to that element which is not currently showed in the recycler?

I expected to do something like recycler.scrollToPosition(15), but the index is outof bunds...
Any idea?

Comment: it shows indexOutOfBounds because you have 15 items. Arrays start counting at 0 so the index of 15th item is 14

Comment: If you have 15 languages and you are loading in recycler view using ArrayList. Then you have to use recycler.scrollToPosition(14).

Comment: Of course, but when I am trying to request focus to that position it says the following. IndexOutOfBoundsException: Sequence doesn't contain element at index 14. Thats because the element of that position is not created yet in the rv. So here is the real problem